# Conditional variables in bash script?

Tags: bash

I'm not used to writing code in bash but I'm self teaching myself. I'm trying to create a script that will query info from the process list. I've done that but I want to take it further and make it so:

1. The script runs with one set of commands if A OS is present.
2. The script runs with a different set of commands if B OS is present.

Here's what I have so far. It works on my Centos distro but won't work on my Ubuntu. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
#!/bin/bash

pid=$(ps -eo pmem,pid | sort -nr -k 1 | cut -d " " -f 2 | head -1)
howmany=$(lsof -l -n -p $pid | wc -l)
nameofprocess=$(ps -eo pmem,fname | sort -nr -k 1 | cut -d " " -f 2 | head -1)
percent=$(ps -eo pmem,pid,fname | sort -k 1 -nr | head -1 | cut -d " " -f 1)

lsof -l -n -p $pid > ~/`date "+%Y-%m-%d-%H%M"`.process.log 2>&1

echo " "
echo "$nameofprocess has $howmany files open, and is using $percent"%" of memory."
echo "-----------------------------------"
echo "A log has been created in your home directory"
echo "-----------------------------------"
echo " "
echo ""$USER", do you want to terminate? (y/n)"
read yn
case $yn in

        [yY] | [yY][Ee][Ss] )
                kill -15 $pid
                ;;

        [nN] | [n|N][O|o] )
                echo "Not killing. Powering down."
                echo "......."
                sleep 2
                ;;
        *) echo "Does not compute"
                ;;
esac
```

Comment: What is the error you get running this under ubuntu?

Comment: Instead of making your script handle different distributions in a different way, it would be more useful to write it in a portable way. If you can answer@Lorunification's question, we might be able to advise you what to change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my version of your script. It works with Ubuntu and Debian. It's probably safer than yours in some regards (I clearly had a bug in yours when a process takes more than 10% of memory, due to your awkward `cut`). Moreover, your `ps` are not "atomic", so things can change between different calls of `ps`.

```
#!/bin/bash

read percent pid nameofprocess < <(ps -eo pmem,pid,fname --sort=-pmem h)
mapfile -t openfiles < <(lsof -l -n -p $pid)
howmany=${#openfiles[@]}

printf '%s\n' "${openfiles[@]}" > ~/$(date "+%Y-%m-%d-%H%M.process.log")

cat <<EOF

$nameofprocess has $howmany files open, and is using $percent% of memory.
-----------------------------------
A log has been created in your home directory
-----------------------------------

EOF

read -p "$USER, do you want to terminate? (y/n) "

case $REPLY in
    [yY] | [yY][Ee][Ss] )
            kill -15 $pid
            ;;

    [nN] | [n|N][O|o] )
            echo "Not killing. Powering down."
            echo "......."
            sleep 2
            ;;
    *) echo "Does not compute"
            ;;
esac
```

First, check that your version of `ps` has the `--sort` flag and the `h` option:

- `--sort=-pmem` tells `ps` to sort wrt decreasing `pmem`
- `h` tells `ps` to not show any header

All this is given to the `read` bash builtin, which reads space-separated fields, here the fields `pmem`, `pid`, `fname` and puts these values in the corresponding variables `percent`, `pid` and `nameofprocess`.

The `mapfile` command reads standard input (here the output of the `lsof` command) and puts each line in an array field. The size of this array is computed by the line `howmany=${#openfiles[@]}`. The output of `lsof`, as stored in the array `openfiles` is output to the corresponing file.

Then, instead of the many `echo`s, we use a `cat <<EOF`, and then the `read` is use with the `-p` (prompt) option.

I don't know if this really answers your question, but at least, you have a well-written bash script, with less multiple useless command calls (until your `case` statement, you called 16 processes, I only called 4). Moreover, after the first `ps` call, things can change in your script (even though it's very unlikely to happen), not in mine.

You might also like the following which doesn't put the output of `lsof` in an array, but uses an extra `wc` command:

```
#!/bin/bash

read percent pid nameofprocess < <(ps -eo pmem,pid,fname --sort=-pmem h)
logfilename="~/$(date "+%Y-%m-%d-%H%M.process.log")
lsof -l -n -p $pid > "$logfilename"
howmany=$(wc -l < "$logfilename")

cat <<EOF

$nameofprocess has $howmany files open, and is using $percent% of memory.
-----------------------------------
A log has been created in your home directory ($logfilename)
-----------------------------------

EOF

read -p "$USER, do you want to terminate? (y/n) "

case $REPLY in
    [yY] | [yY][Ee][Ss] )
            kill -15 $pid
            ;;

    [nN] | [n|N][O|o] )
            echo "Not killing. Powering down."
            echo "......."
            sleep 2
            ;;
    *) echo "Does not compute"
            ;;
esac
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm going to work on your suggestions today and let you know how it works out.

Comment: Works great now. Thank you so much. I was trying to reinvent the wheel but you showed me a much easier way. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this for example by (update)

```
#!/bin/bash

# place distribution independent code here
# dist=$(lsb_release -is)

if [[ -f /etc/redheat-release ]];
then # this is a RedHead based distribution like centos, fedora, ...
    dist="redhead"
elif [[ -f /etc/issue.net ]];
then
    # dist=$(cat /etc/issue.net | cut -d' ' -f1) # debian, ubuntu, ...
    dist="ubuntu"
else
    dist="unknown"
fi

if [[ $dist == "ubuntu" ]];
then
    # use your ubuntu command set
elif [[ $dist == "redhead" ]];
then
    # use your centos command set
else
    # do some magic here
fi

# place distribution independent code here
```

Comment: I did just that and:
error: 
-bash: lsb_release: command not found.
Assuming these aren't lsb compliant systems.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how I can querey the os name in another universal way. cat /proc/version and cutting doesnt work. the version files are in different places. hmm.

Comment: A quick and dirty way would be to manually create a file that contains the distribution. But i am sure there is a way to figure this out in an elegant way.

Comment: Have you tried running lsb_release as root? Perhaps it is just not in the path?

Comment: Look at the output of `uname -a` on the two distributions and see if that allows you to identify which you're on.  If so, work out more precisely which `uname` option gives you the discriminating information.

Comment: I don't think uname allows to identify the used distribution. Under centos there is a /etc/RedHeat-release while under debian and ubuntu you can check /etc/issue. You can identify which distribution is running by checking these files.

Comment: running lsb_release won't work because it's not installed by default on my centos server. I can't install anything. etc/issue and etc/*-release are a no go as ubuntu and centos don't use those. Uname just gives you the generic linux info and not distro info.